# Oracle 18 xe weirdness - can't login as new user

Tags: oracle

I'm getting reacquainted with Oracle after several years and Oracle 18 XE is causing some problems.  I use SQLDeveloper to connect as the SYSTEM user.  Then when I create a new user cpp it says that is an invalid user name.  I have to prefix new users with c##, so I created the user c##cpp.  The c##cpp user is there under Other Users.

But when I try to create a new connection as the c##cpp user the connection fails.  I've also tried creating the connection as just cpp, but that fails too.

What's up with creating users in Oracle 18 XE?

-------Update showing my connection parameters-------

[image]

I get the same error if I try to connect with SID XE.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is that Oracle doesn't like lower case user names.  When I put the username in double quotes the connection succeeds:

[image]

This is on Oracle 11.  I gave up on Oracle 18 XE and installed Oracle 11.  What a ridiculous waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome back to Oracle.

Since you've been away, we added a Multitenant architecture. There is a Container Database - it has common users, with names like C##user.

What you're looking for is the actual database where your data is going to live, that's called a pluggable database. There you would go back to creating users, just like you did back before you left.

Make sure you connect to the pluggable database service. The default would be 'XEPDB1' - connect to THAT as sys or system, and then create your users.

Comment: Connected to xepdb1 service as system.  The c##cpp user that I had created previously showed up under Other Users.  When I try to login as c##cpp to the xepdb1 service I get invalid username/password like before.

So I dropped the c##cpp user and added a user cpp in the xepdb1 service.  Still could not create a connection as the cpp user.

Comment: C## users will show up in EVERY database - that's why they're called common users. but you can't login as them to your xepdb1 service. What happens when you try to login as user CPP?

Comment: please update your question and show us exactly how your connection is defined, a screenshot would work